# How to iterate through an xml file if only the root node is provided

Tags: c++, xml, recursion, visitor-pattern, xerces-c

In a complex C++ program, which is using Xerces, I have to iterate through XML files, and I have to modify its tags.

One of the simpliest XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://specificSite/something.xslt"?>
<RootNode xmlns="http://specificSite#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="specific_site# http://specificsite.com/something.xsd">
 <Node>
  <Title>
   <Item1>aaa</Item1>
   <Item2>bbb</Item2>
     <SubTitle>
       <Item4>555</Item4>
       <Item5>333</Item5>
     </SubTitle>
   </Title>
  </Node>
</Root>
```

The program read the chosen XML file.
At the specific point, where I have to write my code, I got the root node of this XML file, which type is an XMLNode*
The root node can have child nodes, those child nodes can have another child nodes, etc (as you can see in the sample XML file).

How should I iterate through the whole XML file and modify each xml tag?
I wrote a recursive function it not worked.
I am planning to apply visitor design pattern, but I am not so familiar with this.
All in all the biggest problem is that, I only can use the root node of the XML.

Comment: Which parts of Xerces' API documentation have you read so far, and are familiar with? What does "it not worked" means? As far as "design patterns" are concerned, you will find that, generally, Buzzword Bingo is not a substitute for learning and understanding API specifications.

Comment: You had a c# program last year the read xml.  Why not do it in c#?

Comment: @jdweng It is another project, cannot use C#.

Comment: xml data typically needs to be processed using recursion, not iteration

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ok, thank you, do you have any concrete idea how to implement this problem using recursion? So I repeat myself, the problem is that I only have access to the root node. Please, give me some useful hint, in order to walk through those xml file via recursion.

Comment: If you show us your attempt at a recursive solution, we can tell you where you went wrong. If you don't show it to us, we can't.

Comment: There are samples for Xerces, for instance a recursive DOM processing https://github.com/apache/xerces-c/blob/master/samples/src/DOMCount/DOMCount.cpp. I kind of can't find any `XMLNode` in their class API, however, not sure whether that is a version issue or you are using some other library providing that node representation.